# Trouble getting automysqlbackup to keep connection to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, backup

I am trying to follow the instructions from the following page to set up backups for mysql. https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/mysql-incremental-backup-point-in-time-recovery/

However, once I get to the step where I run the automysqlbackup, I always get this error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

It seems that despite this error, some backup files are generated.

However, I can't seem to figure out exactly what is causing MySQL to drop the connection. I have tried to increasing the `max_allowed_packet` to 64M, as well as setting up the `max_connections` to 1000, `key_buffer` to 32M, `max_allowed_packet` to 32M and `thread_stack` to 512K to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and figured out a way around it? Or is it even an issue?

Comment: Hi @user2850818 - welcome to StackExchange!  Please check the [faq]

Comment: None of those settings are likely to impact "losing a connection".  Set the `thread_stack` back to what it was; it is generally bad to increase that one.

Comment: Check `*timeout`.  Especially if you know how many seconds it runs before dying.